# Chat layout like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

Im trying to build a chat layout like whatsapp. I don't understand how they were able to place 'date' at bottom in rightmost corner of layout.

1. I saw their code, it uses horizontal LinearLayout in which there is
   message and date side by side, but then how does the 'I love' part
   of message print above date ?
2. Another problem is that if I use relativelayout to push date to extreme right using alignparentright = true, it expands the entire layout to match parent, which is obvious but undesirable

Please advice me on this

Comment: How don't you know if you saw their code?

Comment: @codeMagic I tried doing the same, it did'nt work, it shows message and date side by side

Comment: @codeMagic `FrameLayout`, maybe? I guess, however, that it will cause the message and the time to overlap. WOnt it ?

Comment: I guess adding tab spaces at end of message text and via framelayout placing date at bottom|right, just a thought... lets see, ill try it as soon as I reach home

Comment: Hi Timmy, did you got the sollution..Please provide the answer here..from 2 days am struggling..

Comment: I changed my requirement. Instead of placing date below I placed it to right of name. If you find the solution please post it here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30439423/4600792

Answer (score 1):

As sketchy as it seems, I can only see that end result being accomplished with four text views.

Name at the top, two lines for the message, and one for the date.

One message line extends all the way across and above the date, the other is below it and next to the date.

You would need to test the textview length to see how much text you can apply to it before it starts to cut off, and apply the remainder to the second message textview.

Gross.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `FrameLayout` in which there is a `LinearLayout` at the bottom which contains the name of the sender and the message. Then, add a `TextView` whose `layout_gravity` is set to `bottom|right`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layout and code below to achieve the desired effect. 
[Source code gist](https://gist.github.com/trivalent/00526294fa38072a6034f5dc5910824a)

What I have used is get the width of the text + the time layout and check if this exceeds the container layout width, and adjust the height of the container accordingly. We have to extend from FrameLayout since this is the one which allows overlapping of two child views.

This is tested to be working on English locale. Suggestions and improvements are always welcome :)

Hope I've helped someone looking for the same solution.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using the `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"` tag on the date `TextView`. This will attempt to lay out the `View` as if the container was "pushing" it to the bottom and right corner.

This may or may not work for all `View`s. But as @codeMagic said, if you saw their code, then it should be apparent, right?

Comment: The `right` attribute won't do anything in a  horizontal LinearLayout